# How to carry out predictions of a time series model using LSTM method of RNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to carry out stock market prediction using LSTM model of RNN. [I am following this article](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/stock-price-prediction-using-python/), however, I am not able to understand, in this particular code snippet,

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
y_test_scaled = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
ax.set_facecolor('#000041')
ax.plot(y_test_scaled, color='red', label='Original price')
plt.plot(predictions, color='cyan', label='Predicted price')
plt.legend()
```

where x_test is being entered into model.predict(). x_test essentially consists of values of the time series data that we are trying to predict. If we insert the x_test, into model.predict(), then we are essentially entering the values that we are tryng to predict in the model. Then so to say, we are not carrying out any prediction. If this is the case, then the method given in the article is wrong. Is my conclusion about the article correct?

Why are we entering x_test data (that is to be predicted) into the model to carry out the prediction of future values?

Answer (score 0):

On the website you linked the author makes a split of the data he has avaliable into train and test data. Here he defines his feature sets as x_train and x_test and his label sets as y_train and y_test. The train data is what you use to train your models, the test data is data the model won't see in the training process.

The features are the data you want to feed into your model so that it can predict more or less the labels. In the training process you do the same, you show your model the features and the corrosponding labels so that the model can learn how the data is connected and hopefully generalize it without overfitting.

So what you have there in your code snippet doesn't look wrong, the author uses his test set of labels and feeds them into his model, so that the model can create the labels for it. He then plots the predicted labels against the true labels (y_test) to see how well the model did its job.

Comment: So, how can we carry out predictions into the future using our model?